# Database of all US federal, state and county elections and candidates

Tags: united-states, election

Is there any centralized public resource out there that compiles upcoming elections, candidates, and results for federal, state, and county levels in the US?

I'm trying to do some research, and I need to stay on top of these, but I'm finding it very difficult to find lists of upcoming elections, much less the candidates. Yesterday's elections were a bell-weather of sorts, and there were several people on the ballot I had never heard of, and couldn't find any information of on the Internet in advance. Some states have websites that list some candidates, but they're non-standard and usually missing the data I'm looking for. And almost no counties have any online election presence.

I'm aware of the [Google Civic Information project](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/), which seemed promising, but it looks like Google pulled the plug on it, as none of yesterday's elections were listed in it, and there haven't been any updates or announcements in well over a year. It still lists notes about the upcoming election on "November 6, 2012"...

Comment: While not public, [Ballotpedia](http://ballotpedia.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) may be a useful resource.  The [organization behind it and their associates (Koch brothers, ALEC, etc.)](http://www.prwatch.org/news/2012/11/11791/lucy-burns-institute-publishers-ballotpedia-judgepedia-and-wikifoia-and-her-right) may be of some concern, but the wiki appears to be fairly sticking-to-the-facts as far as election and ballot measure information does.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official government page.  Elections (even federal elections) are administered by the states, so the federal government doesn't really touch it. You would have to figure out where to get the data from each state and compile it yourself.

The FEC compiles [data](http://www.fec.gov/pubrec/electionresults.shtml) on federal elections and publishes once every two years.